# Replace SupportWalletFragment on Fragment view id returns the wrong request code

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-pay

I'm trying to implement Android pay in app.
The Android pay button must be on a Fragment which is replaced from MainActivity.

```
WalletFragmentInitParams.Builder startParamsBuilder = WalletFragmentInitParams.newBuilder()
            .setMaskedWalletRequest(maskedWalletRequest)
            .setMaskedWalletRequestCode(REQUEST_CODE_MASKED_WALLET)
            .setAccountName(accountName);
    mWalletFragment.initialize(startParamsBuilder.build());

    MainActivity mainActivity = getMainActivity();
    mainActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.conteiner_AP, mWalletFragment)
            .commit();
```

This id container(R.id.conteiner_AP) is located in a Fragment view

Following these instructions(https://developers.google.com/android-pay/android/tutorial#obtain_credentials_and_a_client_id_for_your_app), I have to get the maskedWallet in the Activity on method onActivityResult by REQUEST_CODE_MASKED_WALLET which was directed above.

But i get the needed data by strange code(328180 and 262644), not my REQUEST_CODE_MASKED_WALLET

Why does it happen? Can somebody help me?

Comment: What is your REQUEST_CODE_MASKED_WALLET value?

Comment: originally it was 1001. Then it turned out that any value > 0. In any case, the data is returned on 328180 and 262644 codes. My problem is: I can't be sure that these won't come under other codes.

Comment: This may sound insane but what happens if you use a request code <= 255, like maybe try `1`.  Does it still come back garbled?

Comment: Yes, I have more and more suspicions that it is an internal bug of SupportWalletFragment. I tried to put 0 and the result is same.

Comment: I am not sure what this means, but the two codes you are seeing are suspiciously similar in binary:

`328180` --> `1010000000111110100`

`262644` --> `1000000000111110100`

In fact they are separated by exactly 65536 (2^16)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is because you need to call `super.onActivityResult(...)` in your `Activity` `onActivityResult` method.

Look at the numbers you are getting and how they look in binary:

`328180` --> `1010000000111110100`

`262644` --> `1000000000111110100`

Basically what happens is when `SupportWalletFragment` needs to show UI it fires an `Intent` with internal requestCode of 500 (Note: do **not** rely on this number being the same in future releases).  500 in binary is `111110100` which is the common suffix of the numbers you are seeing.

The way the support library directs activity results to fragments is by using the fragment ID as a mask on the upper bits of the request code.  That's why you see either `101` or `100` at the start of the two request codes you are seeing.  Then when you call `super.onActivityResult()` the support library extracts the Fragment ID and directs the result appropriately.

If you add this line of code, you should see the result you want.

Comment: oh.... thanks... it really helped.  Now onActivityResult in activity is called twice: once by the old code, and the second on the fact that I asked. This is much better.